# Creating new dictionary from dictionaries value

Tags: python, scrapy

I have the following values in a list:

```
'image_result': [{'checksum': '701e172bd980177ae1311f265a753582',
               'path': 'full/ee4d4341b88168972e76c61f45b8db10b349f175.jpg',
               'url': 'http://image-url.com/ID71026700-0000-0500-0000-0000033eb03c.jpg'},
              {'checksum': 'e0b3cada2a8377913bc779a16f1d9e36',
               'path': 'full/410c964db8de6138622c1e1b3b94062b69caedc8.jpg',
               'url': 'image-url.com/ID71026700-0000-0500-0000-0000033eb03d.jpg'},
              {'checksum': '39c9a06f221ba584f691f0def0fde2c4',
               'path': 'full/574dcb9a6af1ea7b733e6986c6a10ba815ca23b4.jpg',
               'url': 'image-url.com/ID71026700-0000-0500-0000-0000033eb03e.jpg'}]
```

I'd like to get the 'path' value and format it to the following so it becomes a global `image` key:

```
'image': 'full/ee4d4341b88168972e76c61f45b8db10b349f175.jpg',
'image': 'full/ee4d4341b88168972e76c61f45b8db10b349f175.jpg',
'image': 'full/574dcb9a6af1ea7b733e6986c6a10ba815ca23b4.jpg'
```

The code I have gives me the right output as shown above, but it only saves the last 'path' value because it's overwritten in each cycle of the loop:

```
for x in item['image_result']:
   item['image'] = x.get('path')
```

These are [Scrapy](https://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/intro/overview.html) items and haven't been able to figure out if this is possible without overwriting the item value every time I want to insert a new one. I'm also very new to python and haven't found a way to get around this even though I researched a lot in the last few days.

Comment: Keys are unique in dictionary. Store the images in a list. `images = [a.get('path') for a in item['image_result']]`

Comment: You are just over-writing the values of item by giving same key. You should use x['image'] instead of item['image']

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you're not updating the sub-key, you're creating a global `image` key.

Do that instead:

```
for x in item['image_result']:
   x['image'] = x.get('path')
```

if you want to extract a list of images (stored as a global `images` key) you just need to do:

```
item['image'] = [x.get('path') for x in item['image_result']]
```

Comment: I do want it to become a global key however. Updated the question to make it clearer

Comment: see my edit. You could create a global key containing the images list.